# Card Container region icon contrast

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex21.2

I have a card region where I display an icon on each card. The contrast for the icons is too low - they are barely visible. How can I change the icon color and/or contrast

Answer (score 0):

One option is to modify region attributes (disable "Apply Theme Colors") and use your own `CARD_COLOR` identifier in query (e.g. in a `CASE` expression), such as

```
select empno as card_id, 
       ename as card_title,
       ...
       CASE 
         WHEN instr(deptno, 1) > 0 THEN 'u-color-1'        --> this
         WHEN instr(deptno, 2) > 0 THEN 'u-color-9'
         WHEN instr(deptno, 3) > 0 THEN 'u-color-39'
         ELSE 'u-color-22'
       END as CARD_COLOR
from ...
```

Comment: In 21.2 Apply Theme Colors is checked and disabled for card container so I cannot modify it. Do you know of any workaround?

Comment: I tested it on 20.2; didn't know that it is disabled in 21.2. I don't know what to do, then. Sorry.

Comment: Actually after I unchecked `use Template Defaults`, I was able to disable Apply Theme Colors. Let me try using Card_color identifier

Comment: OK, I added card_color column to my query but where do I use it in attributes on my page?

Comment: You don't. Apex uses it *by default* if it finds column named CARD_COLOR. If you can't make it work, create account on apex.oracle.com, provide developer's credentials and I'll create an example for you.

Comment: It must have changed in 21.2